# Fontname in pdfmapline

Tags: fonts, pdftex, lilypond

I have an issue with ligatures when using lilypond-book and pdflatex.

```
% \pdfmapline{-dummy LMRoman12-Regular}
% Does not work in this case!

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\begin{lilypond}
\relative c'' {c4 d e d} \addlyrics { flie -- ge, Äff -- le!}
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}
```

I found a workaround [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244711/some-normal-letters-from-included-pdf-disappear-in-compiled-document?rq=1) for Roman font, but in my case I get the following warnings:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qcsr.pfb): glyph `f_f' undefined
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qcsr.pfb): glyph `f_l' undefined
```

What is the fontname to be put in the pdfmapline-Statement in this case?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal working example.